# RSpec having trouble stubbing method called with inline rescue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, stub

I'm trying test a method on a controller:

```
def a_method(list)
  @users = []
  list.each do |x|
    if user=User.find(x) rescue nil
      @users << user
    end
  end
end
```

In my Rspec example I have :

```
it "should do something" do
  User.stub :find => 'user'
  controller.a_method([1,2,3,4])
  assigns[:users].should == ['user','user','user','user']
end
```

Problem:

it always rescues the find method `user=User.find(x) rescue nil`, even though I've stubbed it out.
If I remove the `rescue nil` it works fine.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The if conditional doesn't accept a statement modifier such as `rescue` half way into the statement.
You can put the rescue at the end of the complete `if` statement as in:

```
if user=User.find(x)
  @users << user
end rescue nil
```

Answer (score 0):

why don't you use find_by_id instead of find?

find_by_id returns nil if the id does not exists instead of throwing the exception, it's almost the same you are doing but a little faster I guess and cleaner to read it